# Is it possible to use packages dedicated to other ROS distribution?

Tags: ros, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
actually I am working with tum_simulator and ardrone_autonomy. I find some interesting materials and tutorials like:

http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/wiki/index.php/Tag_recognition_using_webcam

http://robohub.org/up-and-flying-with-the-ar-drone-and-ros-handling-feedback/

but packages which are used in this links are a little bit old and are dedicated from older distributions.
Is it possible to use packages dedicated to other ROS distribution? or is there any simple tutorial how to transfer package to catkin standard and use it with Indigo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197551/is-it-possible-to-use-packages-dedicated-to-other-ros-distribution?/) by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2014-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe [ardrone_autonomy](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy) has already been converted to a catkin package, and has been released for ROS Indigo. Just enter `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ardrone-autonomy` into a terminal. Failing that, grab the indigo-devel branch from the Git repository.

As for tum_simulator, it looks like @Gary Servin submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_simulator/pull/4) to get that updated to catkin and Indigo as well.

EDIT: for future reference, see this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild) on migrating from rosbuild to catkin.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on 2014-11-17**:
Thank you for your response. Actually I am using ardrone_autonomy and tum_simulator ported to Indigo. I was wandering if [this](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/wiki/index.php/DRONE_NAVIGATION_BASED_ON_VISION)
tutorials can be used with ardrone but I guess that without changing to catkin - not.